# reformatted data into JSON from CSV, can't get parsing right in D3

Tags: json, d3.js

I had a graph working with CSV but we've decided to get it up and running with JSON instead. I'm having a difficult time parsing the nested pieces so that I can use them.

Here is the fiddle link and the code block (fiddle is not working) - I'm not looking for someone to get the whole thing working... I just need help with the parsing and example of using the data.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mmdc8/

```
d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23726217/progtime.json", function (error, jsondata) {            
        var studyData = d3.entries(jsondata);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(studyData[0]));

        studyData.forEach(function (d) {
            d.value.name = d.value.name
        });
        console.log(studyData.value.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file has the following structure:

```
- details: [...]
- annotations: [...]
- dates: [...]
```

Each one of this fields, contains an array with objects. To access the data, you don't need to use entries:

```
d3.json(jsonUrl, function(error, jsondata) {

   // Handle errors getting or parsing the data
   if (error) { return error; }

   // Parse the dates
   var startDate = new Date(jsondata.dates.StartDate),
       endDate = new Date(jsondata.dates.EndDate);

   // It will print the array of objects
   console.log(jsondata.details); 

   // Print the start and end dates
   console.log([startDate, endDate]);
});
```

**EDIT**: Added access to the dates.

Comment: Ok, great, clearly I was over complicating things. I still cannot get it to understand the date, I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mmdc8/2/ could you give me an example of how I would call the data?

Comment: Sure, I updated the example. Please, mark the question as answered if it solved the problem, so other users know that the solution is there.

Comment: If I want to access jsondata.details.name, how would that look? They are inside of an array and it seems I need to do something differently...

Comment: `jsondata.detail.name` doesn't exist, because `jsondata.detail` is an array. You can access the first element's name with `jsondata.detail[0].name`. In D3, when you use `.data()`, you should provide an array, like `json.detail` for instance. Try coding a smaller example, and create a new question if you need more help.